# Why does the minimum of F correspond to the lowest eigenvalue of L?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, constraints, sturm-liouville

I have been studying variational principles and I have been reading [this set of notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/B6La.pdf). In section 7.1, we study the Sturm-Liouville problem, as described below.

Let $p(x)$, $\sigma(x)$, $w(x)$ be real functions of $x$ defined for $\alpha \leq x \leq \beta$ with $p$ and $w$ positive for $\alpha \lt x \lt \beta$ and consider the following real functionals of the real function $y(x)$:
$$F[y]=\int_\alpha^\beta p(x)(y')^2+\sigma(x)y^2dx,$$ $$G[y]=\int_\alpha^\beta w(x)y^2dx.$$ The problem is to find the function $y$ that minimised $F[y]$ subject to $G[y]=1$, given that $y(\alpha)$ and $y(\beta)$ are fixed.

The E-L equations become $$Ly=\lambda wy,$$ where $L$ is the differential operator $$L=-\frac{d}{dx}\left(p(x)\frac{d}{dx}\right)+\sigma(x).$$
Now suppose $\sigma(x)$ is positive so that $F \geq 0$, and therefore has a positive minimum. We have $$\lambda G=\int_\alpha^\beta yLydx=F-[pyy']_{\alpha}^{\beta}$$
and the lecturer now claims that the boundary term is zero so that $\lambda = F/G \geq0$. Since $F[Ay]=A^2F[y]$ and $G[Ay]=A^2G[y]$ for any constant $A$ and function $y$ such that $F[y]$ and $G[y]$ exist, the original problem is equivalent to minimising $F/G$ so the lowest eigenvalue of $L$ will be the minimum of $F/G$.

I have two questions:

1) Why does the boundary term disappear as claimed? Do we not also need to specify that $y(\alpha)=y(\beta)=0$ or impose some other appropriate constraint?

2) Why is it necessary to specify that $p$ and $w$ are positive and then later to also specify that $\sigma$ is positive? Where do we use these assumptions and why is the specification that $\sigma$ is positive not needed until later?

Comment: 1) You are correct in that the boundary term vanishes provided certain constraint is imposed on $y$ at $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In the context of the note, it is assumed (and I agreed the author should mention that) that $y(\alpha) = y(\beta) = 0$. If you think about it in terms of eigenfunctions, then one realise that eigenfunctions should satisfy homogeneous boundary condition.

Comment: 2) You want the weight to be positive on $(\alpha,\beta)$ because otherwise the condition $G(w) = 1$ doesn't make sense; you want either $p$ or $\sigma$ to be positive on $(\alpha,\beta)$ because otherwise the minimisation problem doesn't make sense (i.e. $F(y)\le 0$ for any $y$); there is no reason a-priori why we would want $\sigma$ to be positive actually, the reason is simply that all the eigenvalues would be nonnegative then.